# Android Studio Git ignores conflict unexpectantly

Tags: git, android-studio

Today I encountered a very odd problem. I merged two branches, and expected to resolve conflicts. However, Android Studio didn't hint there are conflicts on those files. After merging, I found out that the conflict file's content was totally the same as one of two branches to be merge. Very odd.

Here's the log from Android Studio, I was on branch loginDEMO and want to merge branch dev into branch loginDEMO, after merging I found that `MyApllication.java`'s content is totally the same as that in branch loginDEMO, ignoring the change in branch dev.

```
22:06:21.061: [Chat] git -c core.quotepath=false merge dev
22:06:36.953: [Chat] git -c core.quotepath=false add --ignore-errors -- app/build.gradle
22:09:51.733: [Chat] git -c core.quotepath=false add --ignore-errors -- app/src/main/java/ocm/my/chat/View/LoginActivity.java
22:10:10.143: [Chat] git -c core.quotepath=false add --ignore-errors -- app/src/main/java/ocm/my/chat/MyApplication.java
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/build.gradle.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

22:10:10.464: [Chat] git -c core.quotepath=false commit -F C:\Users\jiahao\Desktop\code\Chat\.git\MERGE_MSG --
[loginDemo f21ea3d] Merge branch 'dev' into loginDemo
```

I also found the in local history `MyApplication.java` has this:

[image]

See the left side, the HEAD should point to branch loginDEMO, and it showed the conflict as usual. But Android Studio didn't hint that I should resolve `MyApplicaition.java`'s conflict. It merge two branch like there was not conflict between two branched in `MyApplication.java`.

So what lead to the consequence like that?